# Pygame: Setting a Circle that erases from the surface

Tags: python, pygame

I have a sort of complicated question I guess that I want to know if someone can help me. For a game I am working on, I need a fog of war where only certain points would not be covered with darkness, and I figured the best way would be to set up a surface that has a fill of (0,0,0) to give it the darkness, and then have somehow a second surface exist to erase from the first and show everything underneath.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: This related question may help: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18923/pygame-circular-cropping-masks

Answer (score 2):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()    

display = (1280,720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, 0, 32)
screen.fill((255,255,255)) # Fill the screen white so you can see when fog of war is lifted
fog_of_war = pygame.Surface(display)
fog_of_war.fill((0,0,0)) # creates surface size of the display and fills it black, nothing can be seen.
pygame.draw.circle(fog_of_war,(60,60,60),(200,200),100,0)
fog_of_war.set_colorkey((60,60,60)) #This is the important part, first we drew a circle on the fog of war with a certain color which we now set to transparent.
screen.blit(fog_of_war,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()
```

So the process you were thinking of in your question works just fine. Wherever on your fog_of_war surface that you want to have vision, simply draw something with the color you set as transparent, you can do this in as many places as you want.